# Shazam tagged songs duplicates detector

Tags: gratis, duplicate-files, shazam

Are you aware of the existence of something to detect (and possibly let you delete) duplicates songs on "My Shazam" tagged list? Or do you know of a way to do that?

I'm almost sure Shazam itself doesn't provide this feature.